# Getting error while export data from excel

Tags: t-sql

I am getting following error

```
ERROR:- Incorrect syntax near '+'.
```

while executing following T-Sql

```
DECLARE @DatabasePath VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @DatabasePath = 'E:\ABC.xls'

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table_1]
SELECT  *
FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0',
        'Excel 8.0;Database='+@DatabasePath+'',
        'SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]') AS xlsTable
```

Is there something wrong in T-Sql.
Actually i want to create a stored procedure where i will pass excel sheet path in @DatabasePath input parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont thing this will work for you.

From [OPENROWSET (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312.aspx)

> 'datasource'
>
> Is a string constant that corresponds
>   to a particular OLE DB data source.

Have you tried something like

```
DECLARE @DatabasePath VARCHAR(MAX) 
SET @DatabasePath = 'C:\tada.xlsx'

DECLARE @RowSetString VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @RowSetString = 'SELECT  * FROM OPENROWSET(''Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0'',''Excel 8.0;Database=' + @DatabasePath + ''',''SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]'')'

SELECT @RowSetString

EXEC(@RowSetString)
```

Comment: yes a solution nevertheless! thanks , but i was hoping for something reverse :-) (a dynamic path for excel file as input parameter to stored procedure)

Comment: i mean i don't want to make a dynamic query and use excel path as an input parameter to stored procedure.

Comment: You will have to use a dynamic query from within the stored procedure.

Comment: Ok.means without dynamic query we can't do this.

Comment: Sorry, nut no, yuo would not be able to do this without it.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @DatabasePath VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @DatabasePath = 'E:\ABC.xls'

DECLARE @sql      nvarchar(MAX)
SET @sql = '
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table_1]
SELECT  *
FROM OPENROWSET(''Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0'',
        ''Excel 8.0;Database=' + @DatabasePath + ',
        ''SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]'') AS xlsTable'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```